# Makefile that compiles source code in a sub directory and places it in another subdirectory

Tags: java, makefile

Here is my program structure:

Master directory:

```
Makefile  
src/
bin/
```

I want to be able to compile the files in /src directory and place the subsequent .class files in the /bin directory.

Here is what I have so far:

```
BIN = ./bin/
SOURCE = ./src/

LIST = $(BIN)ContactBook.class

all: $(LIST)

$(BIN)%: $(SRC)%.java
    javac -d $(BIN) $<
```

Comment: You probably need to add `.class` to the end of the target to make that work.

Comment: How would you do it *without* Make?

Comment: Without make I would do:  javac -d ./bin/ ./src/ContactBook.java

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is not correct, you want to compile `.java` files into `.class` files, you currently have no rule to handle this.

```perl
SRC := $(wildcard src/*.java)
OUT := bin

LIST := $(SRC:src/%.java=$(OUT)/%.class)

all: $(LIST)

$(OUT)/%.class: src/%.java | $(OUT)
    javac -d $| $<

$(OUT):
    @mkdir $@
```